# How to pass references as arguments to Ink! contract messages (or constructors)

Tags: ink, smart-contract

Getting this error while trying to build an Ink! contract with a message accepting a reference argument

```
   |
95 |         pub fn some_message(&self, account_id: &AccountId) -> bool {
   |                                                    ^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
help: consider introducing a named lifetime parameter
```

Adding a named lifetime parameter (as suggested by compiler) doesn't help either:

```
error: ink! messages must not be generic
  --> /home/greez/dev/polkadot/ink/examples/is-contract/lib.rs:95:29
   |
95 |         pub fn some_message<'a>(&self, account_id: &'a AccountId) -> bool {
   |                             ^^

error: could not compile `is_contract` due to previous error
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this issue is that currently Ink! messages and constructors are not allowed to take simple references as arguments, as they are required to be `Sized` and `scale::Decode`.

Until this has been improved (see this tracking [issue](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/989)), possible workaround could be to add private methods that take their arguments as references, to call them from inside messages or constructors.